# compiling livemedia as dynamic library: undefined references to virtual functions

Tags: c++

I am trying to compile the livemedia libraries as a shared object, so I get the following .so:

- libBasicUsageEnvironment.so
- libgroupsock.so
- libliveMedia.so
- libUsageEnvironment.so

It seems to be good, but when I try to link against these libraries, I get a lot of errors of undefined reference to the virtual functions they use.

For what I understood so far, if in a class a virtual method is defined as

```
class MyClass
{
   ...
   virtual myMethod (int arg) {...};
   ...
}
```

the method is correctly found and linked, but if the code is split in a .h file

class MyClass

```
{
   ...
   virtual myMethod (int arg);
   ...
}
```

and in a .cpp file

```
MyClass::myMethod (int arg)
{
...
}
```

it does not work any more.

Now, I admit I'm far from being a C++ guru, but why does this happen? Is it a bug of g++? Or is there some hidden feature of the language? If I compile it as a static library is works.

Comment: Is it only the virtual functions that's giving you problems?

Comment: yes I have the problem only for virtual functions.

Comment: I add another thing I just discovered. It seems that not all the symbols are correctly resolved in the library. For example 

`nm .libs/libliveMedia.so | grep AMR`

gives

`U _ZNK14AMRAudioSource8MIMEtypeEv` which is one of the missing symbols and is virtual. So the problem seems to by in the creation of the .so no in linking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not a compiler bug. It indicates that the function definitions are found in the library `.so` rather than the header, which further implies that you are not linking correctly.

Comment: I think I don't understand your answer. Writing virtual myMethod (int arg); in the .h file is not enough to define the function? Why do I have to implement the function in the .h and not in the cpp file?

Comment: @Ottavio: No, either is fine. But if you had defined the function in the header file, then you would probably not be getting linker errors. Therefore, you must be defining it in a source file. Therefore, you are not linking that compiled source file properly. _Or_ you compiled the shared libraries wrongly.

Comment: Well, this afternoon I tried to compile all the code not as a library but as part of the program and I still get the problem. Thus I'm starting to think that it's a library problem or due to g++...

Comment: @Ottavio: Why does everybody do that? First assume that it's _your_ fault. It's **highly unlikely** to be a bug in `g++`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you're missing a -l (minus small L) switch in the linker command line to the library that contains the needed symbols.